# unable to activate existing conda environments

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, environment

I have created a Conda environment in Pycharm called Practice using Python3.7. I am using a Mac and using the Pycharm terminal (fish) however i receive the same error using iterm2.

when i type `conda activate Practice` i receive the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 138, in main
        return activator_main()
      File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 1098, in main
        print(activator.execute(), end='')
      File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 182, in execute
        return getattr(self, self.command)()
      File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 156, in activate
        builder_result = self.build_activate(self.env_name_or_prefix)
      File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 301, in build_activate
        return self._build_activate_stack(env_name_or_prefix, False)
      File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 378, in _build_activate_stack
        self._replace_prefix_in_path(old_conda_prefix, prefix))
      File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 628, in _replace_prefix_in_path
        if path_list[last_idx + 1] == library_bin_dir:
    IndexError: list index out of range

`$ /usr/local/anaconda3/bin/conda shell.fish activate Practice`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
        CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
             CONDA_PREFIX=/usr/local/anaconda3
    CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base)
         CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/usr/local/anaconda3/bin/python
               CONDA_ROOT=/usr/local/anaconda3
              CONDA_SHLVL=1
                     PATH=/usr/local/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:
                          /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/anaconda3/bin
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>

     active environment : base
    active env location : /usr/local/anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /Users/RossRoberts/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/RossRoberts/.condarc
          conda version : 4.8.0
    conda-build version : 3.18.8
         python version : 3.7.3.final.0
       virtual packages : __osx=10.14.6
       base environment : /usr/local/anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /usr/local/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /Users/RossRoberts/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /usr/local/anaconda3/envs
                          /Users/RossRoberts/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-64
             user-agent : conda/4.8.0 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.3 Darwin/18.7.0 OSX/10.14.6
                UID:GID : 502:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
```

i have already run `conda init fish` and restarted my shell and even tried restarting the machine and i'm still receiving the same error.

This issue is preventing me from running code because my project interpreter is configured to this environment but any time i try to install packages it installs to the active environment (base).

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. Notice that **/usr/local/anaconda3/bin** is on your **PATH** twice. Make sure you aren't putting that directory on your path yourself.

The `conda init fish` adds a line to your fish configuration that will create a 'conda' shell function, and by appending **/usr/local/anaconda3/bin** to your **PATH**, you are interfering with some assumption that `conda init` makes.

Answer (score 1):

Check your .bashrc or .zshrc config ,modify the conda path config correctly

eg :

```
vi .zshrc
```

then

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/mac/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/mac/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/mac/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/mac/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<

export PATH=/Users/mac/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

chage `/Users/mac/opt/anaconda3/bin` to your own path

after change config , remember source your bashrc or zshrc file

```
source .zshrc
```

it works a lot , unless the conda path config conflict

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue . The path variable was incorrect . Type `echo $PATH` , you will be able to see the current path . I changed that to anaconda directory by executing the following command `export PATH=/home/username/anaconda3/bin`. This resolved my issue.